# PHP + MySQL navigation: How to load 2 levels in 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with my navigation.
I have 2 levels navigation:

1. Super category
2. Category

I have a problem with SQL command. Now I have some like this:

```
$laveMenu_query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT HlavnaKategoria FROM it_navigacia WHERE HlavnaKategoria != 'x' ORDER BY poradie");

while($laveMenu_result1 =  mysqli_fetch_array($laveMenu_query1)) {
    $lavemenu_navigacia1 = $laveMenu_result1['HlavnaKategoria'];
    echo "<li class=\"sliding-element\"><a><h3>$lavemenu_navigacia1</h3></a>";

    $lavemenu_query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT Kategoria FROM it_navigacia WHERE HlavnaKategoria = '$lavemenu_navigacia1'");
    echo "<ul>";

    while($lavemenu_result2 = mysqli_fetch_array($lavemenu_query2)) {
        $lavemenu_navigacia2 = $lavemenu_result2['Kategoria'];
        $lavemenu_odkaz2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM it_navigacia WHERE Kategoria = '$lavemenu_navigacia2' AND HlavnaKategoria = '$lavemenu_navigacia1'");

        while($lavemenu_odkaz2_result = mysqli_fetch_array($lavemenu_odkaz2)) {
            $odkaz2_1 = $lavemenu_odkaz2_result['KategoriaURL'];
            $odkaz2_2 .= $lavemenu_odkaz2_result['Url'].",";
        }

        if($Kategoria==$odkaz2_1) {
            echo "<li class=\"sliding-element\"><a href=\"/$odkaz2_1.html\" class=\"active\">» $lavemenu_navigacia2</a></li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li class=\"sliding-element\"><a href=\"/$odkaz2_1.html\">» $lavemenu_navigacia2</a></li>";
        }

        $odkaz2_1 = "";
        $odkaz2_2 = "";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
    $odkaz_array = "";
    $odkaz = "";
    echo "</li>";
} // level 1
```

This code too long loading the page. I need add all this code in 1 one query. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is taking too long to load, then I think you should look at the performance of each of those queries.  Yes, you can combine these queries into one via a `JOIN`, but it may still take too long if you don't have the correct indexes.  I think you should first run each of these queries with `EXPLAIN` preceding the statement to make sure your tables are indexed appropriately.

If they are indexed correctly, then here is a code example (Unfortunately, this is a best guess.  You should share your table structure and how table relates to itself.  Use sqlfiddle.com to load up sample data and share what your final result set should look like. I also don't understand how a 2 level navigation would need 3 JOINs) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.HlavnaKategoria AS t1HlavnaKategoria, t2Kategoria AS t2.Kategoria , t3.*
FROM it_navigacia AS t1 
JOIN it_navigacia AS t2
  ON t2.HlavnaKategoria = t1.HlavnaKategoria
JOIN it_navigacia AS t3
  ON t3.Kategoria = t2.Kategoria 
    AND t3.HlavnaKategoria = t1.HlavnaKategoria
WHERE t1.HlavnaKategoria != 'x' 
ORDER BY t1.poradie
```

Comment: Yes I have indexed tables OK. I test this query in PHPMyAdmin (mariaDB) and says error at line 1 :-(

Comment: Load up sqlfiddle.com with data and the table structure